# behaviour of real and imaginary parts of a holomorphic function near a pole

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a region in the complex plane and $z_0\in\Omega$. Let $f$ be holomorphic over $\Omega\setminus \{z_0\}$. If $z_0$ is a pole of $f$, then $\lim_{z\to z_0}|f(z)|=\infty$. Is it true
$$
\lim_{z\to z_0} |Re f(z)|=\infty,
$$
$$
\lim_{z\to z_0} |Im f(z)|=\infty?
$$

Comment: It could simply diverge (ie. limit don't exist, not even infinity). In fact, I'm pretty sure that it's always the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are trying to handle a pole, the behaviour the pole, at sufficiently close neighbourhood, is dominated by a term of the form $\frac{1}{z^{n}}$ (ignoring a scaling factor and translation).

Approaching $z$ along the real axis and the imaginary exist show that limit do not exist for neither $|Re(z)|$ nor $|Im(z)|$.

(note: limit still not exist even for non-pole. It is obviously false for removable singularity. And Picard theorem take care of essential singularity)

Answer (score 1):

For each disk $D$ with $z_0\in D\subset\Omega$, $f$ maps $D\setminus\{z_0\}$ onto a neighborhood of $\infty$, which contains a set of the form $\{z:|z|>R\}$ for some $R>0$.  This is a consequence of the open mapping theorem applied to $1/f$.   In other words, $f(z)$ doesn't just go to infinity as $z\to z_0$, it does so while making sure to cover all directions.  Thus $\{\mathrm{Re}(f(z)):z\in D\setminus\{z_0\}\}=\{\mathrm{Im}(f(z)):z\in D\setminus\{z_0\}\}=\mathbb R$ for all such $D$, and the limits do not exist.